# Same vertical margin between table and caption when using both table and longtable

Tags: tables, captions, margins, longtable

I'm using both "normal" tables and longtables in my document. I only want to use longtables for longer tables that need a pagebreak, smaller tables I want to have floating to fit into the best position. I don't want all my tables breaking over pages. So far so good.

My only problem is that the caption works differently for the two types of tables. While for the longtable it basically is just another line on top of the table with the same margin as all the other lines of the table. With the "normal" tables, the caption margin is much bigger. In the picture, the first table is a "normal" table, the second one is a longtable
[image: Different caption margins]
Is there any good way to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is a minimum working example. In this case it's the other way around, but the margins are still different from each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |}
\caption{This is a longtable}\\
\hline
Something & something else\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
Something & something else\\
\hline
\endhead
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
Lots of lines & like this\\
Lots of lines & like this\\
Lots of lines & like this\\
end{longtable}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{This is a normal table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Lots of lines & like this\\
\hline
Lots of lines & like this\\
\hline
Lots of lines & like this\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE?

Comment: @Arne Of course. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the package `caption` will fix the issue. Then you might setup the caption using `\captionsetup[<float type>]{<options>}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{caption} % needed  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it, skip= 5pt} % setup the table caption

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c |}
        \caption{This is a longtable}\\
        \hline
        Something & something else\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \hline
        Something & something else\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        Lots of lines & like this\\
        Lots of lines & like this\\
        Lots of lines & like this\\
    \end{longtable}
        
        \begin{table}[ht!]
            \centering
            \caption{This is a normal table}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                Lots of lines & like this\\
                \hline
                Lots of lines & like this\\
                \hline
                Lots of lines & like this\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        
    \end{document}
```